# Data Standards for Bioacoustics: Is there a GBIF for Bioacoustics?

Tags: standards

GBIF, the [Global Biodiversity Information Facility](https://www.gbif.org/), is:

> an international network and data infrastructure funded by the world's
> governments and aimed at providing anyone, anywhere, open access to
> data about all types of life on Earth.

and it's goal is to make biodiversity occurrence data and metadata accessible worldwide.

Shared repositories require common terminology such as those identified by [DarwinCore](https://dwc.tdwg.org/) as well as metadata standards such as those identified by [AudobonCore](https://www.tdwg.org/standards/ac/).

**Is there a GBIF- like platform (with associated terminology/metadata standards) for Bioacoustics data?**

Comment: There should be, I think!  Again, the EU has its own standards on noise, but not bioacoustics.

Comment: Not that I know of, but there should be!  The closest thing I could think of would maybe be the Macaulay library, but strict metadata fields aren't necessarily required from my understanding of it.

Answer (score 5):

Bioacoustica https://bio.acousti.ca is a bit like this.

Associated paper: https://academic.oup.com/database/article/doi/10.1093/database/bav054/2433187